# How to filter objects by value of one of its fields in django?

Tags: django, django-models, slug

I have django application with urls.py:

```
path('<str:slug>/', views.article),
```

When user types name of product in my website, the view is triggered:

```
def article(request, slug):
    videos = models.Video.objects.filter(article=slug)
    return render(request, 'videos/at_detail.html', {'videos': videos})
```

If I add `print(slug)` somewhere in function it returns the word I entered in url, so this part works.

*models:*

```
class article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True, default=None)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Articles"


class Video(models.Model):
    video_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    file = models.FileField()
    article = models.ForeignKey(at, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title) + " - " + str(self.at)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Videos"
        verbose_name = "Video"
```

What doesn't work, and what I'm trying to do, is to get all objects, which have same value 'article', that what I entered in my url. So for example: if I type `127.0.0.1:8000/blueberry/` I will get all objects with field `article=blueberry`.

Is this possible and if it is, how can I do that?

**Edit #1**

Instead of `videos = models.Video.objects.filter(article=slug)` I wrote `videos = models.Video.objects.filter(at__slug=slug)` as @AnkitTiwari commented. It gets rid of error but if I `print(videos)` I get empty query set: `<QuerySet []>`. I have videos in my database though. If I do `videos = models.Video.object.all()` and `print(videos.title)` I get title of one video in my database. If I do this thing with 2 videos I get an error, which says I can't display title of 2 elements. But I get query set with info of 2 videos.

**So, why is my query set empty although I have videos in my database?**

Comment: Instead of **`article`** you've to access it's **slug** eg. ***`Video.objects.filter(article__slug=slug)`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Video.objects.filter(article__slug__iexact=slug)` ?

Comment: Yes, it does exact same thing

Comment: what is the output of ```Video.objects.all().values('article__slug')``` ?

Comment: <QuerySet [{'article__slug': 'tadej'}, {'article__slug': 'tadej'}]>

Comment: Ok, so if you use tadej as slug it should work. Can you please check if ```Video.objects.filter(article__slug__iexact='tadej')``` returns the entries too